# CSS outro transition animation

Tags: html, css

Here is a HTML. If i add transition rule it has outro transition. But when i add animation rule it animation does not work.

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <span>Hover me!</span>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
       <p>CONTENT</p>
    </div>
 </div>

<style>
.dropdown{
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
}

.dropdown-content{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    margin-left: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    z-index: 1;
    animation-name: anim1;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    width: 600px;

}
@keyframes anim1{
    0%{
       opacity:0;
    }
    100%{
       opacity:1;
    }
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

</style>
```

So how do i make outro animation on CSS???

Comment: Do you want something like this [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/chegv6yg)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this code:

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}
.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  margin-left: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 600px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s linear;
  transition: all 0.4s linear;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <span>Hover me!</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p>CONTENT</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you could change the `linear` to another transition of your choice.

By using `-webkit-transition`, `-moz-transition`, `-o-transition` & `transition` you have support for most popular browsers.

If you have anymore questions or you want something different, just ask me.

Here is a fiddle with `linear` transitions: https://jsfiddle.net/f5ryq3yg/ (graph http://easings.net/ at the top of the page)

Or one with `ease-in-out` transitions: https://jsfiddle.net/skvykpsj/1/ (graph http://easings.net/#easeInOutSine)

Comment: Hi @GlBayarra if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is create animation.

```
@keyframes { 0%{ margin:0; } 100%{ margin:100%; }
```

etc.